# ngModel : constexpr error in my angularjs app, but same code on jsfiddle is good

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, version

I have a very surprised error in [my app](http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/pmr/new.php#/carte) with this code:

```
<div class="ui toggle checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="pimp.init.carte.choice_1" ng-checked="pimp.init.carte.choice_1 == 'online'" ng-true-value="online" ng-false-value="offline" />
    <label>OSM 
        <span ng-show="pimp.init.carte.choice_1 == 'online'">en ligne</span>
        <span ng-show="pimp.init.carte.choice_1 == 'offline'">hors ligne</span>
    </label>{{pimp.init.carte.choice_1}}
</div>
```

In the controller, `pimp.init.carte.choice_1` is set by default to 'online'.

I have this error:

> ngModel:constexpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/ngModel/constexpr?p0=ngTrueValue&p1=online

I tried to [repeat the behavior in a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69CAF/98/) but it's seems ok here, so I don't understand why it's not working in my app.

What is wrong ?

Comment: mb related to conflist with other included libraries? i.e. jquery

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using Angular **1.3.11** in your app, and **1.2.1** in your example.

You get the error because of the following change instroduced in **1.3.0-beta.15**:

> ngTrueValue and ngFalseValue now support parsed expressions which the
>   parser determines to be constant values.
>
> BREAKING CHANGE:
>
> Previously, these attributes would always be treated as strings.
>   However, they are now parsed as expressions, and will throw if an
>   expression is non-constant.
>
> To convert non-constant strings into constant expressions, simply wrap
>   them in an extra pair of quotes, like so:
>
> ```
> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="..." ng-true-value="'truthyValue'">
> ```

In your case change the following:

```
ng-true-value="online" ng-false-value="offline"
```

To:

```
ng-true-value="'online'" ng-false-value="'offline'"
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/yvTlKwa0NlWZoyWXWVXH?p=preview

Comment: Yes, there is no more errors, but model is not updated when i switch the checkbox

Comment: My answer is correct. I looked at your site and the issue you have now is because you are using the Semantic UI checkbox. When you click it the underlying checkbox is not clicked, so Angular doesn't change the model.

Comment: If you can't find a solution for it you should post another question regarding this new issue, or take a look at something like this: http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-semantic-ui